# Can I inhibit logging parameters sent to a controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

The last step in one of my current projects is creating a Zip archive using Ruby's 'rubyzip' gem. To do this I create the contents of the archive, place those contents into a parameter called *zip_content* and send it to my controller's *show* method, where the user can click a button to download the archive to their computer.

In development mode Rails automatically writes the contents of the parameters passed to a controller method to the console as well as log/development.log. Normally when I'm developing a Rails application I like to see the parameters passed to my controller methods, like so:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LongStringOfCharacters==", 
"project"=>{"archive_file"=>"ARCHIVE_2019-10-02T154945.zip",  
"zip_content"=> ... long string of binary data snipped ... },
"commit"=>"Download ARCHIVE_2019-10-02T154945.zip"}
```

The part of the application that creates the archive is working just fine, so I don't really need to see the parameters for debugging purposes, especially sinze *zip_content* is very long and full of binary data and clutters up the screen.

Is there a way to inhibit logging the parameters for this one method?

I'm using Rails 6 for this project, if the version is important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb` file change this default line

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

to

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password, :zip_content]
```

Hope that helps!